# Canonical projection to subspace is a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, $V$ a closed set, and $U$ and open set such that $V\subset U \subset X$. Consider the quotient topology and let $\pi$ be the canonical projection into $X/V$.

I want to show that $pr=\pi|_{U-V}:U-V\rightarrow (U-V)/V$ is a homeomorphism. It feels like it might be a general thing that $\pi$ is a homeomoprhism. I am having trouble showing that $pr$ is a homemorphism.

Attempt: Continuity is clear since $\pi$ is continuous. It is clearly surjective since we have restricted the domain to the image. To show injectivity, assume $pr$ is not injective. Then for some $x\neq y \in U-V$ we have $pr(x)=pr(y)$. But this implies $x$ and $y$ were in $V$ giving a contradiction.

I am not sure how to show that the inverse is continuous. And I feel like there is an easier way to approach this.

Comment: Isn't this false, though?

Comment: I think the title is false (I couldn't think of a better way to title it), but I don't think what I have in the question is false. The quotient map only throws away the information that is in $V$, so when we restrict to $U-V$ it acts as the identity.

Comment: @T.Stark Isn't $(U-V)/V$ just $U-V$?

Comment: @R.Burton I am using $U-V$ to denote the elements in $U$ that are not in $V$. And $X/V$ to denote the image of $X$ in the quotient topology.

Comment: @R.Burton is right.  $(U-V)/V$ doesn't make any sense.  I mean, what subset of $U-V$ are you collapsing?  $V$ isn't a subset of that.  The only possible interpretation would be as something like $Y/\varnothing$, which is $Y$ vacuously.

Comment: @Randall I thought it was clear that I meant canonical projection into the quotient topology. I'll add that into the body

Comment: @T.Stark  you should be clear about what $(U-V)/V$ should mean.  There is a standard meaning of space/subspace, but you're appearing not to be meaning it.  (Or, if you are, apply R. Burton's comment.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only is this not false, it is trivially true. 
$U-V$ is open in $X$ if and only if $\pi(U-V)$ is open in $X/V$

Comment: "Not only is this not false, it is trivially true." - come again?